# python remove file from one directory to another

Tags: python, directory, operating-system, filesystems, shutil

I was trying to move the files from a folder to another one on my local machine using `shutil.move`. But I kept getting this error:
[image]

I think it occurs because the destination does not exist because it is exactly where I going to move it. So how can I make the file existent before moving it there?

Note: here is my codes:

```
import os
import shutil

path = '.\PDF_data\PDF'
record = pd.read_csv('~/Desktop/sec_results1.csv')
for file in tqdm(record['ID Number']):
    pdf = path + '/' + file + '.pdf'
    if os.path.exists(pdf):
        shutil.move(pdf, '~/Desktop/PDF_extracted' + '/' + file + '.pdf')
```

Comment: Try removing the if condition, i think it is checking if the destination file exists.

Comment: I doubt that, as you can see, the condition judgment is satisfied, so there's no need to worry about that

Comment: I'm unclear on what doesn't already exist, are you asking if the source PDF has to exist prior to moving it?

Answer (score 0):

If `'~/Desktop/PDF_extracted'` isn't a directory that already exists, you'll have to create it prior to moving files there. You can do so using [os.mkdir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) or [pathlib.Path.mkdir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html).

The following is how you could accomplish this with either one:

### os.mkdir

```py
fpath = '~/Desktop/PDF_extracted'
if not os.path.exists(fpath):
    os.mkdir(fpath)
```

### pathlib.Path.mkdir

```py
from pathlib import Path 

fpath = '~/Desktop/PDF_extracted'
path_obj = Path(fpath)
if not path_obj.exists():
    path_obj.mkdir()
```

#### Side note:

Working with filepath's can be tricky so I would definitely recommend looking into some of `os` and especially `pathlib`'s filepath manipulation methods, they make life a lot easier and will greatly reduce confusion when performing tasks like this.

#### Additional resources:

- [Python | os.mkdir() method](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-mkdir-method/)
- [Why you should be using pathlib](https://treyhunner.com/2018/12/why-you-should-be-using-pathlib/#:%7E:text=with%20Path%20objects.-,pathlib%20makes%20the%20simple%20cases%20simpler,in%20one%20or%20more%20files%3F)
- [Introduction to the Python Pathlib Module](https://stackabuse.com/introduction-to-the-python-pathlib-module/)

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import shutil
path = '.'
print(os.path.abspath(path))
os.mkdir("new_folder")
old_folder = "test"
shutil.move("~/Desktop/test/file.txt", "new_folder")
```

1. You are in the current directory indicated by '.' period sign and if you want to know your absolute path directory.
2. You make 'new_folder' by 'os.mkdir' code
3. Assuming that you have 'test' folder in your current directory '~/Desktop' containing 'file.txt' file to move.
4. 'shutil.move' will help you to move 'file.txt' file from '~/Desktop/test/' folder to '~/Desktop/new_folder' folder.

Answer (score 0):

I did it on Windows 10 so `~\Desktop` can not be recognized. I need to change it into a Microsoft type such as `./../Desktop`.